# Bootstrap iframe alternative

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm using bootstrap to design my website but I seem to have run into a problem.

The website is divided into three sections, a top/header (col-xs-8) section contains some text and a navbar, a right-hand section that contains a todo list (col-xs-4), and a bottom (also col-xs-8 but in a different row) section which I want to update depending on what is clicked on the navbar.

For example, if I clicked on an about me link in the navbar, I would want the navbar and todo list to stay the same, but the third section (bottom) to dynamically update.

Is there anyway to do this without using iframes?

Thanks

Comment: Its a lot more than that. This is a bit more specific to bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap or no bootstrap, the answer is the same.

Comment: Thats true. But there is no implementation in there that seems to work for me

Comment: There there is no implementation in the world that seems to work for you (although I don't understand what the problems with the suggestions there are).

Comment: No need to get personal

Comment: I'm not getting personal, I'm pointing out that you've dismissed all the options without explanation and expressing bafflement.